# тонкости указателя на массив

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Известно, что если не иметь оператора `sizeof` то кол-во элементов массива возможно посчитать, например, так:

```
int arr[10];
size_t size = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
```

где

`arr` есть указатель на первый элемент

`&arr` есть указатель на весь массив

`&arr + 1` есть указатель на следующий кусок памяти после нашего массива

`*(&arr + 1)` есть адрес элемента который идет после последнего элемента массива.

и соответсвенно разность указателей даёт кол-во элементов между ними.

Вопросы:

1. Не приведёт ли это `*(&arr + 1)` к `UB` ?
2. Каким образом `&arr` есть указатель на весь массив ? Это определено стандартом ?

Comment: *"Не приведет ли к UB"* Вот чтобы не думать об этом, лучше так не писать. :) Есть же `std::extent_v` для этих целей.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну конечно же так писать не стоит, вопрос больше теоретический

Comment: Про (1) не знаю, а вот про (2) могу сказать. `&` - одна из немногих вещей (как и `sizeof`), которая не превращает массив в указатель на его первый элемент. Так что он с массивами работает так же, как и с остальными типами. *"Это определено стандартом?"* Конечно.

Comment: `arr` это массив, а не указатель на первый элемент (хотя массив может неявно преобразовываться в указатель на первый элемент)

Comment: @VTT тогда почему *arr дает значение первого элемента ?

Comment: `*arr` эквивалентно `*static_cast<int *>(arr)` Если бы `arr` был указателем на первый элемент, то `&arr` дал бы вам указатель на указатель на первый элемент, а не указатель на массив. И да, разыменовывание `*(&arr + 1)` будет неопределенным поведением, так как указатель `&arr + 1`  не указывает на валидный объект.

Comment: Потому что почти при любом использовании массив неявно преобразуется в указатель на свой первый элемент. Это называется *(array-to-pointer) decay*. Этого *не* происходит при применении к массиву `&` и `sizeof` и еще в кое-каких редких случаях.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan а вы попробывали скомпилировать ?

Comment: @VTT,   std::end(arr) тоже не указывает на валидный обьект, однако используется для проверки достижения конца. И тут тоже  &arr + 1  не разыменовывается, поэтому без разницы какой там обьект или мусор

Comment: Sorry, я вот даже не могу представить тот воспалённый разум, который привёл бы к такой архитектуре...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Речь идет именно о применении (явном или неявном) оператора `*` к невалидному указателю. В `std::end(arr)` нет такого применения. В рассматриваемом выражении - есть. Об этом и речь.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`*(&arr + 1)` может быть записано как `(&arr)[1]` или как `1[&arr]`. Именно в таком "более интересном" виде этот вопрос периодически всплывает в обсуждениях.

В С++ формального ответа на этот вопрос не существует. Тема когда-то активно обсуждалась, но так и застряла в состоянии "drafting":

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232

Никаких поползновений дать окончательный ответ на этот вопрос пока не видно. То есть до сих пор в языке С++ нет ответа на давний вопрос о том, можно ли делать так

```
int arr[10];

for (int *p = &arr[0]; p != &arr[10]; ++p) // `&arr[10]` - UB или нет?
  ...;

for (int *p = arr; p != 1[&arr]; ++p) // `1[&arr]` - UB или нет?
  ...;
```

Вопрос о формальной легальности по крайней мере первого варианта известен еще со времен Царя Гороха, но вменяемого ответа на него до сих пор не предоставили.

В языке С предприняли попытки разрешить часть таких ситуаций, объявив соседние операторы `&` и `*` "аннигилирующими" друг друга еще до начала вычисления выражения. Это легализовало вариант `&arr[10]`

```
&arr[10]  <=>  &*(arr + 10)   <=>  arr + 10 - нет UB
```

Но это формально не легализовало вариант `1[&arr]` (ваш вариант). В этом варианте мы имеем

```
 (int *) *(&arr + 1)
   ^     ^^^^^^^^^^^ 
   |     выражение, результат которого имеет тип `int [10]`
   |
   стандартное неявное преобразование массива к указателю
```

Точно так же, как язык С объявил соседние `&` и `*` "аннигилирующими" друг друга, надо было бы соседнее "неявное преобразование массива к указателю" и оператор `*` объявить "коллапсирующим" до просто преобразования указателя, т.е. считать это выражение эквивалентным

```
 (int *) (&arr + 1)
```

Однако этого пока сделано не было. То есть в языке С ваш вариант формально порождает неопределенное поведение.

В языке С++ все пока (и уже давно) подвешено в воздухе.

Comment: Значит за массивом может быть не достаточно доступной памяти для такого же массива, чтобы взять его адрес, или как?...

Answer (score 0):

По стандарту оператор & берет адрес операнда и фактически превращает в массив из одного элемента.

> For purposes of pointer arithmetic ([expr.add]) and comparison
>   ([expr.rel], [expr.eq]), an object that is not an array element whose
>   address is taken in this way is considered to belong to an array with
>   one element of type T.

Далее простая адресная арифметика. В данном случае элементом массива является массив из десяти элементов целого числа. Поэтому инкрементирование указателя приведет к переходу на следующий элемент массива. После чего остается только взять указатель на первый элемент следующего элемента (извините за тавтологию) и получить их разницу. Разименование `*(&arr + 1)` даст указатель на первый элемент следующего массива `int arr[10];`, а по сути указатель останется тот же, только с типом `int*`.

Указатель и то, на что он указывает это разные вещи. Место в памяти не имеет никакого значения, указатель можно инкрементировать сколько угодно. В данном случае работа идет с обычным числом, которое является указателем:

```
int arr[10];
auto sp = &arr;
sp++;
sp++;
sp++;
sp++;
//size_t size = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
size_t size = (int*)sp - arr; // По сути тоже самое
```

Судя по стандарту все нормально. Ни к какому UB это не приведет. И да, в стандарте это все определено.

Чтобы лучше продемонстрировать можно взять более простой тип:

```
int a;
int *pa = &a;
int *pb = pa + 1;
size_t s = pb - pa;
```

> if P and Q point to, respectively, elements x[i] and x[j] of the same
>   array object x, the expression P - Q has the value i − j.

В данном случае получим размерность массива, которая будет равна единице.
Если нужно получить размерность типа  тогда можно сделать следующее:

```
size_t s = (char*)pb - (char*)pa;
```

Но лучше не изобретать велосипед и использовать sizeof.