# Почему обращение к нулевой памяти в выражении не дает исключение?

Tags: c++, c, указатели, память

Есть структура:

```
struct S {
        char   m0;
        double m1;
        short  m2;
        char   m3;
    };
```

Вот так работает:

```
std::cout << &(((S*)0)->m1) << std::endl;
```

Вот так кидает исключение `нарушение прав доступа...`:

```
std::cout << (((S*)0)->m1) << std::endl;
```

Почему так происходит? Ведь в первом подвыражении так же имеется обращение к невыделенной памяти.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При вычислении выражение вида `E1->E2` преобразуется в эквивалентную форму `(*(E1)).E2`. [expr.ref / 2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#2):

> The expression `E1->E2` is converted to the equivalent form `(*(E1)).E2`;

Получаем, что выражение `((S*)0)->m1` интерпретируется как выражение `( *((S*)0) ).m1`. Т.е. здесь происходит разыменование нулевого указателя *объектного типа*, что является неопределённым поведением. Данное утверждение основано на следующих пунктах стандарта языка.

[expr.unary.op / 1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#1):

> The unary `*` operator performs *indirection*: the expression to which it is applied shall be *a pointer to an object type*, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an *`lvalue` referring to the object* or function to which the expression points.

В результате разыменования указателя получается lvalue ссылающееся на **объект**, но нулевой указатель не указывает ни на какой объект.

[dcl.ref / Note 2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#note-2):

> In particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by indirection through a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior.

Здесь явным образом говорится, что разыменование нулевого объектного указателя приводит к неопределённому поведению.

Связанные вопросы на enSO:

- [Is null reference possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4364536)
- [C++ standard: dereferencing NULL pointer to get a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2727834)
- [Is dereferencing a NULL pointer considered unspecified or undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39929099)
- [The apparent underspecification of one-past-the-end subscripting: for both raw arrays and std::vector. Has it been resolved decisively already?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39860732)

---

Таким образом поведение обоих выражений `&(((S*)0)->m1)` и `(((S*)0)->m1)` не определено, т.к. их вычисления требует разыменования нулевого объектного указателя. И при этом не важно, что компилятор в процессе оптимизации может избежать фактического обращения к «объекту», на который указывает указатель.

Стандарт языка не предъявляет требований к [неопределённому поведению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/900292/262953). Программа может успешно компилироваться и проявлять ожидаемое поведение, либо завершаться с ошибкой в процессе работы, либо может наблюдаться какое-либо иное поведение.

---

На самом деле ситуация с разыменованием указателя, не указывающего на объект, немного сложнее. Взглянем на следующий пример:

```
char a[10];
//Т.к. a[10] эквивалентно *(a+10), то UB - разыменовали указатель на гипотетический элемент за последним элементом массива.
char *b = &a[10];
```

Между этим примером и примером из вопроса

```
std::cout << &(((S*)0)->m1) << std::endl;
```

есть определённое сходство — фактически, значения «объектов», на которые указывают указатели *не важны*.

Здесь `&a[10]`, нам не важно, какое значение находится за последним элементом массива — нам нужен указатель на элемент за последним элементом массива. Аналогично здесь `&(((S*)0)->m1)` нам не важно конкретное значение поля `m1`, нас интересует указатель.

Было бы неплохо доопределить поведение приведённых фрагментов кода в соответствии с интуитивными ожиданиями.

Более того в стандарте языка есть некоторая несогласованность. В описании оператора `typeid` определяется результат разыменования нулевого указателя. [expr.typeid / 3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.typeid#3):

> When `typeid` is applied to a glvalue whose type is a polymorphic class type, the result refers to a `std​::​type_­info` object representing the type of the most derived object (that is, the dynamic type) to which the glvalue refers. If the glvalue is obtained by applying the unary ``* operator to a pointer<sup>57</sup> and **the pointer is a null pointer value, the `typeid` expression throws an exception of a type that would match a handler of type `std​::​bad_­typeid` exception**.

Было предпринято несколько попыток легализовать разыменование указателя, не указывающего на объект в тех случаях, когда фактически не требуется доступ к  значению.

В языке C операторы `&` и `*` в некоторых контекстах являются аннигилирующими по отношению друг к другу (см.: [тонкости указателя на массив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924659)).

В языке C++ пытались ввести особую разновидность lvalue — *empty lvalue*, но эти попытки так и остались на стадии черновика (см.: [Is indirection through a null pointer undefined behavior?](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232)).

---

Есть одна ситуация, когда стандарт языка требует довольно строгую проверку от реализаций на наличие неопределённого поведения в выражениях — это константные выражения.

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    int m;
};

int main()
{
    static S s;
    constexpr const int* p = &(((S*) &s )->m);
    std::cout << p;
}
```

Данный код успешно компилируется и выполняется ([g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d808040f0bc1eec3), [clang](https://ideone.com/iWAdJr)).

Но если попытаться разыменовать нулевой указатель (даже если фактический доступ к значению не требуется), то получим ошибку компиляции.

```
constexpr const int* p = &(((S*) 0 )->m);
```

[g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ec0e00559299cf2):

```
error: dereferencing a null pointer in '*0' 
constexpr const int* p = &(((S*) 0 )->m);
```

[clang](https://ideone.com/YRScbY):

```
error: constexpr variable 'p' must be initialized by a constant expression
constexpr const int* p = &(((S*) 0 )->m);

note: cannot access field of null pointer
constexpr const int* p = &(((S*) 0 )->m);
```

Answer (score 4):

Вообще-то во втором случае вы *обращаетесь* к памяти (смотрите на значение но некорректному адресу), а в первом — *нет*: вычисляется адрес поля, т.е. просто выполняется простая арифметика (с учетом выравнивания), *без реального обращения к памяти*.

Не знаю, насколько это поведение корректно (нет ли какого UB с точки зрения стандарта), но на практике — это просто вычисление `offsetof` для поля, ничем не угрожающее.

Из stddef.h в VC++:

```
#if defined _MSC_VER && !defined _CRT_USE_BUILTIN_OFFSETOF
    #ifdef __cplusplus
        #define offsetof(s,m) ((::size_t)&reinterpret_cast<char const volatile&>((((s*)0)->m)))
    #else
        #define offsetof(s,m) ((size_t)&(((s*)0)->m))
    #endif
#else
    #define offsetof(s,m) __builtin_offsetof(s,m)
#endif
```

Сомневаюсь, что найдется компилятор, который реально будет выполнять разыменование в данной ситуации...

Comment: UB есть - там есть *оператор стрелка*, а это разыменование указателя вникуда, которое [по определению UB](https://habr.com/ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/250701/)

Comment: @gbg ну такая конструкция используется в макросе `offsetof`

Comment: @Barracudach - про этот макрос на [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) написано столько компромата, что лично я его просто не применяю.

Comment: Фразы *offsetof cannot be implemented in standard C++ and requires compiler support* уже достаточно для того, чтобы исключить данный костыль из своей практики.

Comment: Конечно, все равно не понятно, как это может работать. При разыменовывании у нас получается lvalue, которое имеет адрес и значение, а значение не может быть высчитано из неопределенного адреса. Единственное как я могу это понять для себя - выражение оптимизируется компилятором, и дело не доходит дальше оперирования адресами. Но все равно сбивает с толку синтаксис, противоречащий стандарту.

Comment: Да нигде это *значение* не используется. Вы что, хотите сказать, что значение `&(((S*)0)->m1)` зависит от того, что находится в памяти `((S*)0)->m1`? Эдак вы скажете, что в `int n = 5; int * p = &n;` адрес в переменной `p` зависит от значения в переменной `n`...

Comment: @gbg Пересмотрел еще раз https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof — что-то особой ругани не заметил...

Comment: А `offsetof` это все-таки специальная конструкция, определенная стандартом. Так что не стоит надеятся, что похожий собственный код будет работать так же. Тем более, что обычно используется специальный встроенный оператор.

Comment: @user7860670 В данном случае это ответ на комментарий *исключить данный костыль из своей практики*.

Answer (score 3):

Как это часто бывает в случаях, когда поведение не определено, ошибкой тут является само ожидание какого-то определенного результата. Нет даже оснований считать, что конструкция вида `((S*)0)->m1` обязана приводить в программе к разыменования нулевого адреса. Это разыменование присутствует в коде, а вот чем оно обернется в программе - это неизвестно. Оно может быть выполнено, а может быть пропущено (так как компилятор в праве предполагать, что в программе не бывает разыменования нулевых указателей), а может поломать кодогенерацию и приводить к совсем неожиданным последствиям.

Comment: А кстати, в стандарте сказано где-то, что `0` и `NULL` — это одно и то же? Или `nullptr` и 0? Нулевой адрес — это `NULL`/`nullptr`, а не 0, вроде же так? И, кстати, значит, в выражении `&((S*)1234)->m1` все в порядке :)

Comment: @Harry, `0` и `nullptr` не одно и то же. Но преобразование выражений `0`, `NULL` и `nullptr` в указательный тип формирует нулевое указательное значение (_null pointer value_).

Comment: @Harry Нет, `0` - это целочисленный литерал типа `int` и он может использоваться в качестве значения null pointer, `nullptr` - это уже литерал типа `std::nullptr_t`, а NULL - это вообще макрос. Хотя в этом контексте они все будут взаимозаменемы по идее.

Comment: @wololo А, ну, значит, в `((S*)1234)->m1` все нормально? Здесь же нет разыменования *нулевого указательного значения*?

Comment: @Harry, если указатель `(S*)1234` не указывает ни на какой _объект_, то это также UB. Сможет ли компилятор понять куда указывает такой указатель — зависит только от фантазии разработчиков компилятора. А с учётом того, что функция отображения между целочисленными типами и указателями implementation-defined, то я бы таких штук `(S*)1234` избегал.

Comment: @wololo Тут наверное будет UB даже если `(S*)1234` действительно указывает на экземпляр живого объекта `S`, так как не использован `std::launder`