# Разыменование nullptr без фактического обращения - почему нельзя?

Tags: c++, неопределённое-поведение

Собственно, вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define OFFSET_OF(TData, field) ((char*)&(((TData*)nullptr)->field) - (char*)nullptr)


struct TEST_STRUCT
{
    char    field0;
    int     field1;
    double  field2;
    char    field3;
};


int main()
{
    printf(
        "offset of field1: %zu\n"
        "offset of field2: %zu\n"
        "offset of field3: %zu\n",
        OFFSET_OF(TEST_STRUCT, field1),
        OFFSET_OF(TEST_STRUCT, field2),
        OFFSET_OF(TEST_STRUCT, field3)
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Компилируем, запускаем:

```
offset of field1: 4
offset of field2: 8
offset of field3: 16
```

Дизассемблируем, смотрим, что сгенерировал компилятор:

```
.text:0000000140003370 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:0000000140003370
.text:0000000140003370
.text:0000000140003370 ; int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
.text:0000000140003370                 public main
.text:0000000140003370 main            proc near               ; CODE XREF: __tmainCRTStartup+2EB↑p
.text:0000000140003370                                         ; DATA XREF: .pdata:00000001400072A0↓o
.text:0000000140003370                 sub     rsp, 28h
.text:0000000140003374                 call    __main
.text:0000000140003379                 mov     r9d, 16
.text:000000014000337F                 mov     r8d, 8
.text:0000000140003385                 mov     edx, 4
.text:000000014000338A                 lea     rcx, aOffsetOfField1 ; "offset of field1: %zu\noffset of field2"...
.text:0000000140003391                 call    printf
.text:0000000140003396                 xor     eax, eax
.text:0000000140003398                 add     rsp, 28h
.text:000000014000339C                 retn
.text:000000014000339C main            endp
.text:000000014000339C
.text:000000014000339C ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Видим, что всё работает как надо. Компилятор, как и ожидалось, предвычислил значения смещений на этапе компиляции. Никакого *явного* UB не произошло.

Однако в моём предыдущем вопросе один не особо дружелюбный пользователь назвал такой код вакханалией и бредом. Мол, тут разыменуется `nullptr`, и по-этому так делать нельзя. Однако, хоть разыменование и происходит, но оно ведь тут чисто формальное! *Реального* обращение к памяти через `nullptr` тут ведь не происходит! Более того, код данного макроса выполняется ещё на этапе компиляции, и по факту его результат - константы!

Соответственно, у меня вопрос: почему так нельзя делать? Если такая конструкция работает и не приводит к UB, значит ответ прост - так *можно* делать. Если же такой код небезопасен, то просьба объяснить, чем именно. Приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода, где выполнение конструкции `((char*)&(((TData*)nullptr)->field) - (char*)nullptr)` приведёт к реальному UB!

P.S. Я знаю, что существует "стандартный" макрос `offsetof`, однако мой вопрос не о нём.

Comment: Я всегда так делаю и это работает (значит можно, а если в каком-нибудь компайлере нельзя, значит просто не нужно такой компайлер использовать)

Comment: Можно жить с UB если в документации на конкретный компилятор сказано "это UB из стандарта мы доопределяем так то". Или если вы проверили сгенерированный код и убедились что он соответствует вашим ожиданиям. Это нормально, если каждый раз когда вы компилируете код, вы проверяете результат.

Comment: [Почему обращение к нулевой памяти в выражении не дает исключение?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1365803/) Вот [пример кода](https://godbolt.org/z/9bPMf58Tr), где использование конструкции `&(((TEST_STRUCT*)nullptr)->field)` приводит к некоторым проблемам. Даже если игнорировать разыменование нулевого указателя, есть ещё одна проблема: вычисление разности двух указателей, которые не указывают на элементы одного массива (или гипотетический элемент за последним), и не являются оба нулевыми, что также [вызывает UB](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#5).

Comment: P.S. Разность двух указателей имеет тип `std::ptrdiff_t`, но в функции `printf` используется спецификатор преобразования `%u`, что снова вызывает UB. Лучше использовать `%td`. P.P.S. При вычислении разности двух указателей в [некоторых экстремальных случаях](https://godbolt.org/z/Gfe3qcrY1) возможно переполнение типа `std::ptrdiff_t`, что опять таки есть UB.

Comment: @wololo я на это, кстати, обратил внимание, и первоначально использовал %zu. Но меня сбило то, что аргументы записываются в младшие 32 бит регистров. Как-то упустил тот факт, что в x64 запись в младшую часть регистров обнуляет старшую. Бывает, особенно когда лежишь с температурой 38+))

Comment: @wololo Интересно. GCC не дает скомпилировать такой жирный объект, а кланг - не против...

Comment: @wololo "При вычислении разности двух указателей в некоторых экстремальных случаях возможно переполнение типа `std::ptrdiff_t`" - ну это проблема не переполнения `std::ptrdiff_t`, а проблема переполнения разрядной сетки в целом. Но честно, я не могу представить себе такие монструозные структуры в реальной жизни)) На практике, их даже не получится использовать, т.к. попытка выделить под них память приведёт к исключению `bad_alloc`. И кстати, я однажды объявил структуру не такую экстремально большую, но в ней тоже был массив на несколько сотен мегабайт. Так мой MinGW завис при компиляции))

Comment: @LShadow77, а вообще-то, конечно, можно и не ломать копья, а использовать встроенный [offsetof](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/offsetof.3.html) (думаю, это вполне устроит всех пуристов)

Comment: @avp проблема в том, что мне надо использовать `offsetof` для поля-параметра, который передаётся шаблону. Её суть в этом вопросе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359535/gcc-can-i-use-offsetof-with-templated-pointer-to-member. В ответе рекомендовали разыменование `nullptr`! И это, на мой взгляд, показательный пример того, как разработчики стандарта сами толкают программистов на нарушения их правил и внедрение UB в свой код. К слову, раз в стандарт добавили "указатели" на поля, то могли бы разрешить приводить их к `size_t` - получилась бы отличная замена `offsetof`. Но нет, не их путь!

Comment: @LShadow77, imho вы на правильном пути, ведущем вообще к отказу от С++ ...

Comment: @avp я может и отказался бы, да только есть ли альтернатива?)) Вот появился бы эдакий Че Гевара от мира кодинга, пришёл бы к разработчикам стандарта и устроил революцию, реформировал систему, отменил все UB...))) Но кроме шуток...

Comment: @LShadow77, если кроме шуток, то я просто пишу на Си программы, которые решают конкретные задачи для конкретной аппаратуры (и при случае делюсь своими знаниями)

Answer (score 6):

"UB" - не то же самое, что "код не работает".

> пример кода, где ... приведёт к реальному UB!

UB - это то, про что в стандарте написано, что это UB (либо то, про что в стандарте вообще ничего не написано - но это редкость).

Из этого следует, что наличие UB нельзя определить, глядя на вывод программы или в дизассемблер. Нужно смотреть в стандарт, а там написано вот что:

[`[expr.unary.op]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#1)

> ... If the operand points to an object or function, the result denotes that object or function; otherwise, the behavior is undefined except as specified in [[expr.typeid]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.typeid#3).

То есть неважно, используется результат или нет - все равно UB. (Единственное место, где это можно делать без UB - в аргументе `typeid(...)`).

---

Почему в стандарте так написано? Предполагаю, что потому, что в компиляторах есть оптимизации, и для целей оптимизации удобно считать, что UB никогда не происходит (компилятор может не заходить в ветку `if`, в которой видит разыменовывание нулевого указателя, экономя на проверке условия, и т.п.).

Проще оптимизировать, считая что нулевые указатели никогда не разыменовываются, чем вводить хитрые правила, когда результат считается "использованным", а когда нет.

---

Можно ли так делать на практике?

Пытаться оправдывать UB есть смысл, только когда оно дает какие-то новые возможности. Когда есть стандартный `offsetof(...)`, незачем оправдывать свою реализацию.

Даже если на вашем компиляторе это вроде работает, вы уверены, что это не сломается в каком-то другом месте кода, при обновлении или смене компилятора, или при изменении флажков?

Когда у вас в следующий раз появятся таинственные краши непонятно где, вам придется перепроверять все свои грязные хаки.

---

Если хотите реальные примеры, то вот. Не совсем то же самое, но похоже. [При обновлении на GCC 6 сломались Хром, Qt и KDevelop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36893251/2752075), потому что GCC стал выбрасывать проверки `this != nullptr`, потому что вызов метода на нулевом указателе - UB, даже если никакие поля оттуда не читаются.

Ну и: (но это не столько про UB, сколько про недостаточные проверки в макросе)

```
#include <iostream>

#define OFFSET_OF(TData, field) ((char*)&(((TData*)nullptr)->field) - (char*)nullptr)

struct A {int field;};
struct B : virtual A {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << OFFSET_OF(B, field) << '\n';
}
```

На GCC ошибка компиляции, на Clang - краш.

Comment: А мне кажется, что эти многочисленные UB просто признание разработчиков в своей криворукости, невозможности  разобраться во внутреннем устройстве сделанного ими монстра под названием С++...

Comment: @avp Вот, у меня складывается такое же мнение. Причём очень многие UB декларированы в стандарте по-сути искусственно, отрезая программистам хорошие возможности для оптимизации, в том числе процессоро-ориентированной. Многие возможности искусственно ограничены (тот же offsetof, или VLA не приняты стандартом) .Причём компилятор, как правило, никак не уведомляет программиста о том, что он нарушил очередной запрет, который разрабы стандарта добавили в свой многотомный талмуд! Я слышал мысль, что любой серьёзный проект на C++ содержит UB, о которых не догазыватся разработчики...

Comment: @LShadow77 Все эти многочисленные UB (разыменование нулевого указателя, разность указателей, не указывающих на элементы одного массива, переполнение `ptrdiff_t`, некорректное использование спецификаторов преобразования в `printf`, узкоспециализированный `offsetof` и т.д. и т.п.) есть тяжелейшее наследство, пришедшее из языка C.

Comment: @wololo а разработчики стандарта языка C++, получается, это наследство только усугубляют всевозможными запретами, игнорирование которых, однако, в 99% случаев приводит к работоспособному хорошо оптимизированному коду. Но в какой-то момент - бац!.. и новая версия компилятора этот код ломает.

Comment: @LShadow77 Чего они там усугубили? Все UB, которые я указал в комментариях к вопросу, есть и в C. Скоро пол века будет, как стандартизаторы C не могут их устранить.

Comment: @wololo, десятки лет (пока в дело не включилось новое поколение разработчиков, воспитанных на С++)  эти UB в Си никак себя не проявляли, будучи вполне легальными фичами языка

Comment: @LShadow77 *"никак не уведомляет программиста о том, что он нарушил очередной запрет"* В идеальном мире нужно на каждый пул-реквест собирать билд с санитайзерами и гонять тесты (`-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`, или что-то подобное). Тогда, например, на ваш макрос будет красивый ворнинг в рантайме. *"отрезая программистам хорошие возможности для оптимизации"* Примеры бы не помешали...

Comment: @wololo Про `printf` у современных компиляторов отличные ворнинги, если сделать их ошибками - проблем никогда не будет. Про `offsetof` - что вы имеете в виду? Что его не на всех классах можно использовать? (Тут согласен, это муть какая-то. Все компиляторы его принимают на всех классах, только иногда нужно ворнинги выключать.) Про `ptrdiff_t` - а что с ним?

Comment: @LShadow77 Я даже рад, что VLA не приняли. В том виде, в котором они есть в С, они добавляют очень много сложности. Они только кажутся простой фичей. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8dd6s7nT5 В каком-то более простом виде - да, было бы полезно. Но в любом случае можно руками звать `alloca()`.

Comment: `Про offsetof - что вы имеете в виду? Что его не на всех классах можно использовать?` Да. `Про ptrdiff_t - а что с ним?` Если разность двух указателей не представима типом `ptrdiff_t`, то UB. Я в общем-то не оправдываю обилие UB в C/C++ (как раз наоборот, я за то бы их все вырезали по максимуму везде, где только можно) и даже не ваш ответ критикую. Я возражаю против нападок в комментариях на C++ в данном конкретном случае. Да, в C++ есть свои специфичные UB, но обсуждаемые в данном вопросе UB были уже как минимум в [C89](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html): ...

Comment: ... `If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is undefined... Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary * operator are a null pointer... Permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results...` Никаких послаблений на случай, когда фактическое обращение к объекту не требуется, никаких послаблений на случай, когда вычисления можно провести во время компиляции. Максимально жёсткие формулировки. Сколько на тот момент лет ещё оставалось до начала стандартизации C++?

Comment: @avp `десятки лет эти UB в Си никак себя не проявляли, будучи вполне легальными фичами языка`.  Десятки лет от стандарта к стандарту вас предупреждают об опасности таких языковых конструкций. Но вы почему-то решили, что раз все предыдущие годы никаких последствий на практике не было (а их точно не было?..), то так будет и впредь. Не вижу предпосылок для таких выводов.

Comment: @wololo, *`Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary * operator are a null pointer`* -- надо быть законченным формалистом, оторванным от реальности (это я скорее не о вас, а об авторах стандартов), чтобы использовать ***dereferencing*** в вычислении offset_of (более общо -- в *вычислении адреса*). Что же касается ptrdiff_t (и заодно уж других signed -- ssize_t и off_f), то проблемы есть, с самого начала мне они представлялись какими-то убогими (а значит не нужными).

Comment: @avp про язык Си я добавлю, что с самого начала он позиционировался, как язык т.н. *среднего* уровня, сочетающий в себе удобство языка высокого уровня и низкоуровневые возможности, характерные для ассемблера. Отсюда и такая свобода в переопределении типов указателей и наличие пространства для разного рода трюков. А С++ появился, как всего-лишь улучшенная версия С, поддерживающая ООП. Да, у такой свободы есть проблема - ответственность программиста за свои ошибки. Но это проблема криворукости программиста, а не языка. Но вот пришли разработчики стандарта, и эту свободу убили на корню!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat вот тут я реализовал новый вариант со множественным наследованием: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/EQHGqI4T0UyBbw. Плюс переделал иерархию, добавил итератор и функцию сортировки.  Буду признателен, если проверите. А то с этими UB из коробки я как-то подрастерял уверенности (надеюсь, это пройдёт).

Comment: @LShadow77 Ух, много кода... UB вроде нет (если работает и не падает с `-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined`, я бы не беспокоился). В `class NodePointer` можно выкинуть `operator=` и `operator!=` и все равно будет работать так же (второе автоматически через `==`, первое через аналогичные конструкторы). На будущее, лучше кладите на гитхаб или pastebin, так удобнее...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, большое спасибо за неоценимую помощь! Буду развивать дальше...

Answer (score 1):

Небольшой ликбез по UB: Стандарт языка описывает эффекты от использования различных языковых конструкций в виде работы некоторой абстрактной вычислительной машины. А *Неопределенное Поведение* - это те случаи, когда поведение этой абстрактной вычислительной машины в стандарте не определено. От компиляторов же стандарт требует, чтобы в ходе реального выполнения программы она выдавала то же *Наблюдаемое Поведение*, что и описываемая в стандарте абстрактная вычислительная машина.

Единственное прямое следствие наличия в коде конструкций, поведение абстрактной вычислительной машины для которых в стандарте не определено, - это невозможность определить *Наблюдаемое Поведение* этой абстрактной вычислительной машины и, соответственно, невозможность иметь какие-либо ожидания по поводу работы такой программы в реальности.

В фразе *"Видим, что всё работает как надо. Компилятор, как и ожидалось, предвычислил значения смещений на этапе компиляции."* оборот "как и ожидалось" не имеет под собой оснований. И вообще любые попытки определить наличие или отсутствие в коде Неопределенного Поведения путем сборки и выполнения программы обречены на неудачу.

*"Однако в моём предыдущем вопросе один не особо дружелюбный пользователь назвал такой код вакханалией и бредом. Мол, тут разыменуется nullptr, и по-этому так делать нельзя."* - да, вакханалия там еще та, причем разыменование нулевого указателя там как вишенка на торте из других проблем.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150604/discussion-on-answer-by-user7860670--nullptr---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.