# Как реализовать цикл обработки элементов матрицы с помощью указателей? Без использования i, j?

Tags: c, указатели, матрицы

Как реализовать цикл с помощью указателей без использования i,j?
Примерно таким методом(если получится)

int *p;
...
for (p = &a[0][0]; p <= &a[NUM_ROWS-1][NUM_COLS-1]; p++)

```
int schet = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < cols - 1; i++) 
{
    for (int j = i + 2; j < cols; j++) {
        if (matrix[i][j] != 0)
            schet++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Например вот так foreach(arr as t)...

Comment: метку  языка добавьте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как раз таким методом, как вы просили:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_ROWS    3
#define NUM_COLS    5

int main()
{
    //динамически выделяем память под матрицу NUM_ROWS*NUM_COLS
    int (*matrix)[NUM_COLS] = new int[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];

    //для примера: заполняем матрицу случайными значениями [-3..4]...
    //...и выводим её
    srand(time(NULL));
    puts("Matrix:");
    for (int i=0; i<NUM_ROWS; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<NUM_COLS; ++j)
            printf("%2d ", matrix[i][j] = (rand()&7) - 3);
        puts("");
    }
    puts("");

    //подсчитываем количество ненулевых элементов, используя указатель
    int schet = 0;
    for (int* p = &matrix[0][0]; p < &matrix[NUM_ROWS][0]; ++p)
        if (*p) ++schet;

    //выводим результат
    printf("Number of the non-zero elements is %d!\n", schet);

    //освобождаем память
    delete[] matrix;

    return 0;
}
```

Поясню. Матрица с размером `M`x`N` в C/C++ представляется в памяти, как обычный одномерный массив из `M*N` элементов. Соответственно, выражение `[i][j]` преобразуется компилятором в `[i*N+j]`, где `N` - число столбцов (а `M`, соответственно, это число строк). Следовательно, с помощью указателя мы можем пройтись по матрице, как по одномерному массиву, начиная с элемента `[0][0]` (который имеет эквивалентный индекс `0` в одномерном массиве) и заканчивая элементом `[NUM_ROWS-1][NUM_COLS-1]` (эквивалентный индекс которого `(NUM_ROWS-1)*NUM_COLS+(NUM_COLS-1)` = `NUM_ROWS*NUM_COLS-1`). Несуществующий "элемент", следующий за последним (которого мы не должны достигнуть), соответственно имеет двухмерный индекс `[NUM_ROWS][0]` (потому что `NUM_ROWS*NUM_COLS`, как известно - это количество элементов в матрице).

Comment: Не могли бы вы дать ответ в вопросе по ссылке,там указан полный код программы, и подробное задание,прошу прощение за неудобства. Тут немного не то что нужно,я так понимаю у вас цикл пробегается по всем элементам матрицы и подсчитывает количество ненулевых элементов. Также, можно ли обойтись без "puts" пока еще не знаком с этим. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1414829/%d0%a3%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b/1414873#1414873

Comment: Заголовок вопроса "Указатели на двумерные массивы",я новый пользователь,не в курсе, возможно ссылки не отображаются

Comment: @qqueeez ответил в контексте данного вопроса. А `puts("")` - то же самое, что `printf("\n")`, переход на следующую строку при выводе.

Comment: Работа с двумерным массивом как с одномерным, формально вызывает [неопределённое поведение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1197662). Поведение выражения `&matrix[NUM_ROWS][0]` также [не определено](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924642).

Comment: @wololo Если так, то уж очень формально. Настолько формально, что это ub фактически можно не брать в расчёт. Ведь написано же чётко: "consists of a **contiguously** allocated", т.е. n-мерный массив можно смело "растягивать" в одномерный. Хотя я, к примеру, всё же предпочитаю представлять матрицы в виде исключительно одномерных массивов и явно вычислять индексы типа `i*NUM_COLS+j`. А ещё лучше `(i<<pitch_shift) | j`, для пущей производительности.

Comment: `это ub фактически можно не брать в расчёт` Возможно так и есть. `Ведь написано же чётко: "consists of a contiguously allocated", т.е. n-мерный массив можно смело "растягивать" в одномерный.` Знание фактического расположения объектов в памяти относительно друг друга не гарантирует, что некое UB будет работать ожидаемым образом. Просто для примера: [1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e6dd5e6744eca10), [2](https://rextester.com/WBRFE59038).

Comment: @wololo ха, так первый пример не про массивы, а про то, в каком порядке компилятор распределяет переменные в памяти - это другое. А второй пример вообще должен выдать синтаксическую ошибку, и он так же про другое.

Comment: @LShadow77, эти примеры про то, что знание фактического расположения объектов в памяти относительно друг друга не гарантирует корректность работы с указателями. `второй пример вообще должен выдать синтаксическую ошибку` Какую?

Comment: @wololo `"что знание фактического расположения объектов в памяти"...` Мы знаем, что элементы массивов и матриц следуют в памяти один за другим - про это сказано в документации. Но как именно компилятор располагает в памяти отдельные переменные, как раз таки `мы не знаем`! Даже если, допустим, они следуют в порядке объявления, то как минимум между ними может оказаться заранее неизвестное выравнивание, зависящее от компилятора и платформы, под которую компилируем. По-этому пример 1 вызывает реальное ub, а не формальное, как в случае с указателями на элементы матрицы.

Comment: @wololo `int* p1 = malloc(sizeof(int));` - `error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*'`. То же самое с `realloc()`.

Comment: @wololo однако, не смотря на приведённые вами не совсем удачные примеры, c утверждением `"знание фактического расположения объектов в памяти относительно друг друга не гарантирует корректность работы с указателями"` я всё же вынужден согласиться. Вернее, я бы так выразился: ***не всегда*** гарантирует. Потому что всё испортить может его вреднейшество Оптимизатор. И я с таким примером однажды столкнулся на личном опыте: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1105521/381066 (мой первый вопрос на SO, кстати)) )

Comment: `Мы знаем, что элементы массивов и матриц следуют в памяти один за другим - про это сказано в документации` — это не важно. Да, между подмассивами нет паддингов, но это не важно. Не могу понять вашу логику. Каким образом из непрерывности матрицы следует законность произвольных манипуляций с указателем? Когда в стандарте языка написано ровно противоположное: `The behavior is undefined ... An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression a[1][7] given the declaration int a[4][5])`.

Comment: Вся формальность этого UB состоит только в том, что компилятор обрабатывает данное UB ожидаемым образом. По крайней мере пока. Обратите внимание, что в первом примере фактически никаких паддингов между двумя переменными нет. И два побайтово равных указателя (`memcmp` возвращает ноль) при сравнении оператором `==` оказываются неравными.  `int* p1 = malloc(sizeof(int));` — это код на языке C.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int ** i = matrix; i != matrix + cols - 1; i++) {
    for (int * j = *i; j != *i + cols; j++) {
        if (*j != 0) {
            schet++;
        }
    }
}
```

i проходит по указателям на строки матрицы, а j по самим строкам.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]