# Указатели на двумерные массивы

Tags: c, указатели

Дано задание: разработать функцию int is_tridiagonal (int *mat,int n);
mat – это квадратная матрица размером nxn. Функция должна вернуть 1,
если mat – трехдиагональная матрица, и 0 в противном случае.

Трехдиагональная матрица(везде кроме "трех главных" диагоналей стоят 0)

Выполнил задачу элементарным методом, с помощью цикла перебора элементов i-ых - строк, j - столбцов

Но нужно как-то обойтись без этих i,j и решить задачу с помощью указателей

В общем, стоит преобразовать мои циклы примерно на вот такие, не понимаю как это сделать

int *p;
...
for (p = &a[0][0]; p <= &a[NUM_ROWS-1][NUM_COLS-1]; p++)

```
    #include <stdio.h>

#define cols 6

void user_matrix(int matrix[cols][cols]);
void matrix_outp(int matrix[cols][cols]);
int is_tridiagonal(int matrix[cols][cols]);

int main() {
    int matrix[cols][cols];


    user_matrix(matrix);
    matrix_outp(matrix);
    printf("%d", is_tridiagonal(matrix));
}


void user_matrix(int matrix[cols][cols]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf("Enter matrix[%d][%d]: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf_s("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void matrix_outp(int matrix[cols][cols])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            printf("%6d", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
// перебор элементов матрицы и проверка на 0
int is_tridiagonal(int matrix[cols][cols]) {

int schet = 0;

// выше главной и следующей после нее
for (int i = 0; i < cols - 1; i++) 
{
    for (int j = i + 2; j < cols; j++) {
        if (matrix[i][j] != 0)
            schet++;
    }

}
// ниже главной и следующей после нее
for (int i = 1; i < cols; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++)
    {
        if (matrix[i][j] != 0)
            schet++;
    }
}
// 3 главные по центру
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        if (i == j || i == (j - 1) || i == (j + 1)) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
                schet++;
            }

        }

    }
}


            

if (schet == 0)
    printf("Trexdiagonal");
else
    printf("NETrexdiagonal");
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мы можем преобразовать матрицу в указать `int* pointer = &matrix[0][0];` и работать как с одномерным массивом.

Если у нас матрица 5x5, N=5:

```
|1 1 0 0 0|
|1 1 1 0 0|
|0 1 1 1 0|
|0 0 1 1 1|
|0 0 0 1 1|
```

То одномерный массив:

```
|1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1|
```

Если мы разберём матрицы других размеров, то заметим закономерность:

`2xA, 3xB, 3xA, 3xB, 3xA, 3xB, 3xA, 3xB, 2xA`, где A - это 1, а B - это 0, и 2xA - это два раза A подряд и т.д.

Можем заметить, что A повторяется 3 раза, кроме начала и конца, так как три диагонали. А также 3 раза B, рассмотрев другие примеры получим -- N-2 раза подряд (по первой и последней строчке).

Таким образом, мы знаем откуда начинать -- с 3 элемента (2 индекс), сколько шагать -- проверить N-2 элемента, что равны 0, и пропустить 3 элемента (в сумме N+1), а также знаем, где остановиться -- это до предпоследнего элемента `&matrix[N-1][N-2]`!

**Edit:**

[@DmitryK](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/494660/dmitryk) заметил, что я не правильно построил условие, которое верно только для N=5, и то, что я сразу не передаю указатель на матрицу в функцию.

Я изменил свой код. Теперь функция сразу принимает указатель на матрицу, но и не использует больше других указателей. Я проверил для 4,5,6 квадратных матриц, что "3xA" начинаются с индекса `size` и потом увеличиваются на `size+1`.

Идея заключается в том, как теперь мы ходим по развернутому массиву, `++i` просто ходим  на одну ячейку, и если условие выполняется, дополнительно перепрыгиваем три диагонали (3xA) `i += 3`.

`(++i + 1)%(size+1)?:(i += 3)` -- в `(++i + 1)` я инкрементирую i, чтобы перейти на следующую ячейку. Потом я увеличиваю на 1, чтобы индекс стал возможно кратен `size+1`. Потом идет трюк с `?:`, т.е. если номер ячейки, увеличенной на 1, кратен `size+1`, то остаток от деления будет 0. Ноль в условиях - это ложь, поэтому будет выполняться в тернарном операторе часть после `:`, а если будет другое число, отличное от нуля, т.е. истина, то будет выполняться часть после `?` и до `:`, но там ничего нет, поэтому там и ничего не произойдет.

В теле цикла мы просто берём элемент и проверяем не ноль ли он.

Да, код не использует указатель в том смысле, в котором Вы хотели. За это я прошу прощения.

Код:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define N 5

/* Old answer, works only for N = 5
bool is_tridiagonal(int size, int matrix[size][size])
{
    for (int* pointer = &matrix[0][2]; pointer < &matrix[size-1][size-2]; pointer += size + 1)
        if (pointer[0] || pointer[1] || pointer[2])
            return false;
    return true;
}
*/

bool is_tridiagonal(int size, int* matrix)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < size*size-2; (++i + 1)%(size + 1) ?: (i += 3))
        if (matrix[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    int matrix[N][N] = {
        {1,  2,  0,  0,  0},
        {3,  4,  5,  0,  0},
        {0,  6,  7,  8,  0},
        {0,  0,  9, 10, 11},
        {0,  0,  0, 12, 13},
    };
    printf("%d", is_tridiagonal(N, (int*) matrix));
    return 0;
}
```

**P.S. Поправьте меня, если моя логика неправильная!**

Comment: Компилятор выдает ошибку в строке где bool.. "недопустимый параметр" "выражение не определяется константой", в нижнем printf "передано недостаточно аргументов для строки формата" "is_tridiagonal: функция - шаблон не может преобразовать параметр 2 из типа "int[5][5]"".  Будет ли работать данный код если матрица будет задана с клавиатуры или с помощью rand?

Comment: Попробовал собрать в онлайн компиляторе,выдает 1 даже при условии что в матрице все 0

Comment: @qqueeez, перейдите к представлению квадратной матрицы в виде одномерного массива `int a[]` размером `n * n`. В таком случае i,j-ий (i -- индекс строки) элемент матрицы может быть представлен как `a[i * n + j]` / У вас наверное винда и M$ компайлер и он не понимает код в ответе)

Comment: @qqueeez Ругается на bool? Вы импортировали #include <stdbool.h>? Можете заменить bool на int, false на 0 и true на 1. Вы наверное, что кроме %d ещё добавили в printf, но не передали в неё. Сейчас добавлю расширенный код. И да, код будет работать с любым способом записи матрицы.

Comment: Ничего не менял,ctrl + c, ctrl + v, дело в том что код пишу в Visual Studio 2019, возможно из-за этого такие ошибки выдает)

Comment: @qqueeez Очень странно.. Я использую clang с такими настройками `clang main.c -o main -arch arm64 -O3 -Wall -std=c18` под свой MacBook на M1.

Comment: Увидел вашу вторую версию кода ,столько ошибок посыпалось при попытке запуска,может посоветуете какую-нибудь более "адекватную" среду разработки на С?

Comment: 42 ошибки и 4 предупреждения

Comment: @qqueeez Даже не знаю.. Я использую Visual Studio _Code_ и компилятор clang из командной строки (встроенной в VSCode).

Comment: В основном подчеркивает как ошибку int matrix[size][size] в параметрах всех функций

Comment: @qqueeez Вы можете заменить параметры всех функций с `(int size, int matrix[size][size])` на `(int matrix[N][N])`. НО не забудьте заменить везде `size` на `N` в коде.

Comment: @qqueeez Если мой ответ помог Вам, то прошу отметить его как решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: Да,спасибо огромное,вы очень помогли

Comment: А зачем передавать в функцию копию матрицы, и только внутри переводить в указатель? Нужно в функцию передавать указатель `is_tridiagonal(int size, int* p)` и ссылаться на элементы как написал @avp. Вычисления идут с абсолютными числами, а надо вычислять относительно `N`. Иначе если изменить значение `N` - алгоритм ломается `if (*pointer != 0 || *(pointer + 1) != 0`.

Comment: Работа с двумерным массивом как с одномерным, строго говоря, вызывает [неопределённое поведение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1197662).

Comment: @DmitryK Хмм, я не до конца понимаю Вашу идею, как цикл for будет знать, где остановиться? А также, если я всё правильно помню, "Хотя параметр num объявляется как целочисленный массив из десяти элементов, С автоматически преобразует его к целочисленному указателю, поскольку не существует параметра, который мог бы на самом деле принять весь массив. " (ссылка: http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/peredacha-massivov-v-funkcii)
Прошу, добавьте свой ответ!

Comment: @Be3y4uu_K0T В смысле как узнать? Вы же передаете не только массив, но и его размер `is_tridiagonal(N, matrix)`.

Comment: @DmitryK Так ранее Вы говорили `is_tridiagonal(int size, int* p)` p - указатель, как Вы хотите проверять вышел ли указатель за границы?.. (Ещё раз Вас прошу, сделайте своё решение и предложите его)

Answer (score 0):

Код с передачей указателя, место копирования матрицы:

```
bool is_tridiagonal(int size, int* matrix)
 {
    for (int* pointer = matrix + 2; pointer < (matrix + size*size-3); pointer += size + 1)
    {   // вот здесь должен быть цикл до size-2 - иначе при размере матрицы отличным от 5 - будет неправильная работа
        // сами же в описании написали - "B повторяется N-2 раза"
        if (*pointer != 0 || *(pointer + 1) != 0 || *(pointer + 2) != 0) // вот это работает только для N==5
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Кроме того, вы проверяете только что не в диагоналях находятся нули. Но не проверяете, что в диагоналях нули отсутствуют.
И ещё момент, сравнение в условии цикла - нужно посчитать с чем сравнивать, чтобы не было ошибки, т.к. там идет приращение нестандартное `pointer += size + 1`
А ещё нужна проверка что размер матрицы больше 2

Comment: Я понял теперь о чем Вы говорили! Я исправлю свой ответ. Ещё мой компилятор (clang) ругается на `int* matrix` - `warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int [5][5]' to parameter of type 'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`, я подставил Вашу функцию в свой код. Возможно надо добавить мне `(int*) matrix`

Comment: Да, это предупреждение. Разные компиляторы разное выдают. Т.к. при работе с указателями больше вероятность допустить ошибку. Вызов нужно сделать `is_tridiagonal(N, &matrix[0][0])` или `is_tridiagonal(N, matrix[0])`.

Comment: Я изменил свое решение. С "B повторяется N-2 раза".

Comment: @Be3y4uu_K0T Чтобы было на указателях, замените `matrix[i]` на `*(matrix + i)`. Кстати предыдущее решение было тоже ничего, только надо было прямое сравнение заменить на цикл.